# WP media Gallery Child Categories no longer indented (formatting changed)

Tags: php, wordpress, image-gallery

WP media Gallery Sub Categories no longer indented (formatting changed).
What could be causing this behaviour. Refer to attached screen shot. The screenshot with arrow indicates the behaviour of child categories previously and the screenshot without any arrows show how it organises the main categories and sub categories now.

[Showing No Indentation for Child Category. unexpected behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxYmb.png)

[Showing Indentation for Child Category. expected behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqVAT.png)

Some tips to reverse this behaviour will be appreciated.

Comment: It could be so many things; without posting any code or link you are not very likely to get an answer.

Comment: @BenoitLussier will figure out the source code and paste here where possible.

Comment: I found a work around by installing a 3rd party plugin which organised all media gallery categories as main folders and sub folders (Folder structures like it is in Windows). I have migrated all cats in there and stakeholders seems to be satisfied with the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I built custom plugin which organised everything in there as folders and sub folders.